# Multiplication works for dense matrix but not Compressed Row Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

Here are my variables:

```
In [232]:Y=np.ones((1024,1))
In [233]:X=np.ones((1024,1))
In [234]:YY=Y*2
```

this works:

```
In [235]:(YY-X)*X
```

However, this does not:

```
In [236]:(scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(YY)-scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(X))*scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(X)
```

which results in:

```
ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

Now if I want to do this:

```
In [245]: XX=scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(X)
In [246]: YYY=scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(YY)
In [247]: (YYY-XX)*XX
ValueError: dimension mismatch
In [255]: (YYY.todense()-XX.todense())*XX.todense()
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

Can anyone explain why this occurs? As far as I can tell, this should work. I'm probably overlooking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because these examples are not equivalent pieces of code.  What would be equivalent would be if you had

```
> Y = np.matrix(np.ones((1024, 1))
> X = np.matrix(np.ones((1024, 1))
> YY = Y * 2
> (YY - X) * X
```

This would give you `ValueError: matrices are not aligned`.  NumPy has the `array` class and the `matrix` class, and `array` multiplication is not the same as `matrix` multiplication.  With `np.ones`, you construct an `array`, and `array` multiplication is pointwise, while `matrix` multiplication is [Matrix Multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

Comment: Thanks a ton, I figured it just was hacky way to store a very sparse array.